# Как настроить проксирование через nginx? Нужно при переходе по определенному адресу получать то, что хостит убунту-сервер

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx

Как настроить проксирование через nginx?
Есть сервер убунту, поднятый на VirtualBox.
Нужно настроить проксирование, и я не понимаю, как это сделать. Инструкция такая:
Присвойте вашему виртуальному серверу имя example.com при помощи файла hosts.

Настройте проксирование.

Откройте браузер и убедитесь, что tomcat доступен по адресу http://example.com/

Да, там установлен tomcat, и он возвращает главную страницу при запросе {ip}:8080
Как настроить проксирование?

Comment: Я, возможно, использую не те термины, но я только учусь и не понимаю, что происходит))

Comment: Тебе реверс прокси нужно сделать или чё?

Comment: Да, кажется, оно и нужно)

Comment: Я написала, что вообще просят, прям так и написано. И я не уверена, но видимо так и надо

Answer (score 0):

Пример рабочего конфига **без** https:

```
# site1 
server { 
        listen 80; 
 
        access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log; 
        error_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-error.log; 
 
        server_name site1.test www.site1.test; 
 
        set_real_ip_from 93.184.216.34; 
        real_ip_header X-Real-IP; 
 
        location / { 
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.10:8180/; 
            proxy_set_header Host $host; 
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; 
            } 
        } 
 
# site2 
server { 
        listen 80; 
 
        access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log; 
        error_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-error.log; 
 
        server_name site2.test www.site2.test; 
 
        set_real_ip_from 93.184.216.34; 
        real_ip_header X-Real-IP; 
 
        location / { 
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.20:8280/; 
            proxy_set_header Host $host; 
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for; 
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; 
            } 
        }
```

`93.184.216.34` - внешний ip, где крутится демон nginx работающий в режиме реверс прокси.

`127.0.0.*` - внутренние ip на которых крутятся сайты, куда надо пробрасывать запросы из вне.

`server_name` - домен сайта. ya.ru, google.com - вот это вот.

SRC:

https://serveradmin.ru/nginx-proxy_pass/

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64388115

Comment: А где этот конфиг писать?))

Comment: Конфиги хранятся в `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`, но чтобы они работали - надо сделать симлинк нужного файла в `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` и перезапустить нжинкс.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую!

Comment: У меня почему-то не рестартит nginx

Comment: `nginx -t` чё говорит?